# remove a element from concurrentbag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to remove an element from concurrent bag but while removing it removes other object from the bag.

Below is the code that i am trying to execute, in the below code results has a value.
but when i try to remove it removes some other element.  Only option is that i need to remove and insert it again. Can you tell me what is that i am doing wrong in the below code.

I have list of items in _cache.CachedSecurities and i only want to remove specific item from the list.

My goal is to add or update the items but i see in concurrentbag there is not option to do that.

```cs
var results = await _iLevelService.GetObjectsByIdsAsync(GetObjectTypes.Security, result.ToArray());
for(int i = 0; i < results.Count(); i++)
{
    Security item = (Security)results[i];
    _cache.CachedSecurities.TryTake(out item);
    _cache.CachedSecurities.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: I think you're confused about how `ConcurrentBag.TryTake` works. It removes an item from the bag and returns it: in this case, it overwrites `item` with whatever item it has removed from the bag. You can't remove a specific item from the bag.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We don't really have enough information to go on here.

Comment: @canton7 ok so how do i update an item in the concurrent bag?

Comment: Typically you don't, a ConcurrentBag is probably the wrong tool for the job here. From what you've said it sounds like you might want a `HashSet` protected by a lock, but it's hard to say without more details.

Comment: @canton7 is there no way i can remove an element from concurrent bag?

Comment: You can ask it to give you *an* element, you can't tell it to give you a *specific* elmenet

Comment: Maybe a `ConcurrentDictionary` is more like what you want?

Comment: elementat extension method

Answer (score 0):

`TryTake` is a bizarre function because you can't try to take a specific item. It takes any item, as if you are drawing a name out of a bag without looking.

If you need to be able to remove a specific item then you need to use a different collection, like `SynchronizedCollection`:

If you can change `CachedSecurities` to type `SynchronizedCollection`:

```
var results = await _iLevelService.GetObjectsByIdsAsync(GetObjectTypes.Security, result.ToArray());
for(int i = 0; i < results.Count(); i++)
{
    Security item = (Security)results[i];
    _cache.CachedSecurities.Remove(item);

    // Modify item then put it back in

    _cache.CachedSecurities.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If no other thread has access to the `ConcurrentBag` yet (e.g. you are just filtering the results right after retrieving them but before returning them) you can just instantiate another bag without the unwanted item.

```
results = new ConcurrentBag(results.Except(unwantedItem));
```